# In the movie interstellar, how far was Cooper station from Saturn?

Tags: interstellar, space-station

When Cooper was seen floating near Saturn he was well beyond the ring system.  Is it explained anywhere how far the station was from Saturn?

Answer (score 7):

Cooper Station was in **orbit** of Saturn.

> “Cooper Station,” the doctor said. “Currently orbiting Saturn.”

Given that humanity now has gravity-control technology and reactionless drives, there's really no good reason to assume that they were in any *specific* orbit other than just kinda mooching around nearby.

---

For the record, Cooper was found "near" Saturn. Beyond that we don't really get any specifics in the script or novel, but the fact that you can distinguish *individual rings* would suggest that he's something between 100K and 400K from the planet.

> INT. OUTER SPACE - LATER
>
> Cooper FLOATS, dead or unconscious, near Saturn. In the
>   distance we see two Rangers approaching ...
>
> <sub><sup>[Interstellar: Original Screenplay](http://www.raindance.org/wp-content/uploads/FLFinalSPv1.pdf)</sup></sub>
>
> [image]

Comment: "kinda mooching around nearby"? Is this the technical description? :)

Comment: @Martha - Yes. They were orbiting at a distance of approximately one mooch, which as we all know is something like 2.3 kilo-meanders